# How to disable and enable layout according to media player in android

Tags: android, android-layout, audio, android-mediaplayer

First I am using soundpool But with soundpool its difficult to do this task. So I am now using media player. In my app I am playing sound if user press on layout. But the problem is if user press layout again and again. Sound repeating again and again. I want layout become disable if sound is playing and enable when sound finish so that user able to play sound again when its finish.

Code-

```
private LinearLayout layout1;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.boy);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
    layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.layout1);
    layout1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {   
            mp.start();
       });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private LinearLayout layout1; 
MediaPlayer mp; 
boolean flag=false; 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.boy); 
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test); 
layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.layout1); 
layout1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 

public void onClick(View v) { 
if(!flag){ 
 mp.start(); 
 layout1.setEnabled(false); 
 } else{flag =true ;}
}); 

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() { 
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { 
flag=false; 
layout1.setEnabled(true); 
  } 
}); }
```

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755243/how-to-pause-media-player-sound-in-android

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You can do like this in onClickListener:

```
boolean flag;
layout1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (flag == false){   
        flage=true;
        layout1.setEnabled(false);
        mp.start();
    }
 });
```

The value of flag is dependant on state of sound file.

The callback public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) gives you a reference to the MediaPlayer.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        flag = false;
        layout1.setEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: I know how to make layout enable disable but don't know where to enable and where to disable

Comment: Please provide  complete solution according to my code.

Comment: @GopalRao no please help me.

Comment: How to make flag value dependent on state of sound

Comment: @GopalRao I have tried that code but after completion of sound when I click on layout sound not play again.

Comment: Now what to do in onCompletion method?

Comment: I have edited the code. In onComplete you will see if your audio file has finished and if it has you will enable the layout and set flag as false . Do some research on your own as well. If you get stuck somewhere, ask me