# how to pause media player sound in android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have media player in main activity. And sound start with this activity. I want when new activity start audio stop and when I press back from next activity and back to main activity audio starts. Please help me.

Code-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton()
    {
        boy1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boy1);
        boy1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mp.stop();
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Boy1.class));
            }
        });     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mp.stop();
    }

    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        mp.stop();
        finish();
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mp.stop();
    }

}
```

Comment: just use `mp.pause();`

Comment: replace mp.pause() in onPause() and replace mp.start() in OnResume() and remove mp.stop(); in onStop()

Answer (score 2):

try this way:`onPause()`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try{
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
          mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
    }catch(Exception we){
        we.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And `onResume()`

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try{
         mediaPlayer.start();

    }catch(Exception we){
        we.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: when new activity start sound is not stoping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `mediaPlayer.pause();`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pause() method available in MediaPlayer class. This would be useful:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html